# ubuntu network manager openvpn overwrites default route

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I am running VPN server on aws account which hosted under Account A. 
I have another aws Account B, where I have a Ubuntu ec2 instance. On this instance I have installed Openvpn and configured client settings.

Whenever I start my Openvpn client on Account B Ubuntu ec2 instance, I am getting kicked out of server as Ubuntu network manager Openvpn overwrites default route. Also I am unable to ssh connection again without rebooting my host.

My default route before starting vpn client :

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.0.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.0.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Default route after starting openvpn client:

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.9        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         172.0.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        10.8.0.9        255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.9        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.9        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.9        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.0.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I did [Googled](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=network-manager-openvpn%20command&rct=j#q=ubuntu%20network%20manager%20openvpn%20overwrites%20default%20route) it and found that it is known bug and the workaround provided is not working in my case as it is **Ubuntu server**(**CLI not GUI**) on aws with dhcp settings, which I would not like to alter to fix the issue. As there can be multiple server in future.

Have any faced this issue and solved this? Any suggestion would be a great help.

**Just for information** : Same openvpn setting on the server and client config works for my laptop(running windows though) and other machine and I can connect to aws ec2 instances from my lappy without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after digging a lot. I had to disable my push redirect-gateway entry, though it worked with other OS. To work with Ubuntu/Debian I had to disable my push redirect-gateway in server.conf file of Openvpn. That resolved my issue.

Below is my server.conf file output which is working :

```
port 1194
user nobody
group nobody
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/EasyRSA-2.2.2/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/EasyRSA-2.2.2/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/EasyRSA-2.2.2/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/EasyRSA-2.2.2/keys/dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.0.0.1
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
#push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
```